# Make a Talbot carpet

Tags: optics, electromagnetic-radiation, diffraction

I've seen this beautiful images of light being diffracted by a grid. I was wondering how I could make something like that using Python and/or Mathematica.

How does the math behind the [Talbot effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talbot_effect) work to obtain the wave function describing the Talbot carpet?